# Configure Devise Allow Same Email For Multiple Accounts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, twitter-oauth

We have users that want to use the same email address for multiple accounts. Our rails app uses omniauth-twitter gem with Devise to authenticate users. When users sign up, email is required but it is not used for authentication.

How do we configure Devise to allow users to use same email when signing up for multiple accounts without getting "email has already been taken" validation error?

Comment: Remove 'validatable' from devise macro on your User model?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply remove :validatable from the model devise options.

> Validatable creates all needed validations for a user email and
>   password. It's optional, given you may want to create the validations
>   by yourself. Automatically validate if the email is present, unique
>   and its format is valid. Also tests presence of password, confirmation
>   and length.

http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Validatable