# exclude authentication for email (one of the user details) rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

When a user signs up i have three fields: name, email, password

For some users i would like the same email address but then it gives a notification thats already in use.

But i do want devise to authentic my user with name and password...

Do i need to turn off authentication for email?

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
end
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24250143/configure-devise-allow-same-email-for-multiple-accounts You just need to remove `:validatable`

Comment: oke, but then all validtions are off like username/password? or will it still check for usernam and password then?

Comment: It will no longer validate those fields and you'll need to add your own - that's their recommended way to allow duplicate e-mails

Comment: https://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Validatable

Comment: Its not as simple as just disabling the validation. You also need to address how you actually are going to authenticate the users. If you have duplicate emails then which user should be authenticated when they submit a user/password combination? You need another unique identifier for you users.

Comment: yes i think so because when i remove validation and add a separate validation for username and password (so i exclude email) it still gives me an error that two email addresses are the same. So i would like to login with a User name and a Password, and when sign up i would like the option that users can have the same email address